Are questions about financial institutions on-topic?
To the extent that the site is focusing on quantitative finance, it would seem that questions about banks, hedge funds, and other institutions might not be within the scope.  
Prompted by this question:

Wealth Management Vs Asset Management

What is the consensus?  Should we allow questions about institutions involved in quantitative finance, or is that too "meta"?

No. I have updated the FAQ as follows:

The Quantitative Finance Stack
  Exchange is intended specifically for
  professionals and traders working in
  investment banking, and academics
  involved in teaching and research.
Topics include pricing of securities,
  derivatives, options, risk modeling,
  quantitative techniques, and the
  mathematics used in quantitative
  finance.
This is not a place to ask questions
  about general consumer finance or
  personal investments (see
  https://money.stackexchange.com/)

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to improve that.

Ugh, no no no. These types of "Help me understand the FT" questions are going to be the death of this site. That's the kind of nonsense that shows-up on Wilmott.
That same poster also asked:

How do banks actually make money on mortgages

I voted to close both of them.
